# Discord.js limit command to 5 times/day

Tags: node.js, discord

I have the following command, that I want to limit users to only be able to use it 5 times every 24h

```
if(command === "rep") {
  let user = message.mentions.members.first();
  console.log(`[.] ${message.author.username} issued command "rep"`.cyan)
  let amount = 1
  console.log(`[+] ${message.author.username} repped ${user}`.green)
  db.add(`karma_${user.id}`, amount)
  let bal = await db.fetch(`karma_${user.id}`)
  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor(0x3242a8)
  .setTitle("TD Karma Bank")
  .addField("User Repped", `${message.author.username} has repped ${user}!`, true)
  .addField("New Balance", `${user} now has ${bal} karma points!`, true)
  .setFooter("This bot was created by Yote.", "https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/458377279349719073/a_f6b59ba4feb6fc0d7f1b47d659d85091.webp?size=128")
  message.channel.send(embed)
}
```

No clue how to do this, any possible help?

Comment: You would have to track the uses somewhere. I would probably record each use in a database table and include the user id and a timestamp. Before each new entry check to see how many have been entered that day for that user and stop allowing new entries when the limit is reached. This cant be tracked in any sort of secure way without the use of server-side code and some way to identify the user (user account of some sort)